# elastic4s - search in multiple fields

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I'm using the `elastic4s` client for my scala elastic search and trying to search on multiple fields
something like:

`"query": { "match": { "_all": { "query": "SomeTermToMatch", "operator": "and" } } }`

I've tried:

`query { '_all', query(searchString)).operator(MatchQueryBuilder.Operator.AND) }`

But it didn't return the desired result as native es does.

Does someone know how can I achive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form this query as:

```
search in "index" / "type" query {
  matchQuery("_all", "search string").operator(MatchQueryBuilder.Operator.AND)
}
```

You can see a [unit test](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/87886eafe62232bbe629be811010d596edca6109/src/test/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/query/MatchQueryTest.scala#L20-L27) in the elastic4s source that shows this working.

Comment: Thank you very much! and for the great client as well. (Though, it could be very helpful if there was more documentation)

Comment: BTW, is there a way to get response (hits array) as json, or I must parse?

Comment: What I'm doing now is very crooked:
`net.liftweb.json.Serialization.write(res.getHits.getHits.map(f=>JSON.parseFull(f.sourceAsString)`

Comment: Only what you're doing I think

Comment: Can you answer my question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735854/elastic4s-finding-multiple-exact-values-for-one-term