# Elastic4s - finding multiple exact values for one term

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I'm trying to filter a term to be matching one of the values in an array.

relaying on the ES https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html

```
 GET /my_store/products/_search
            {
                "query" : {
                    "filtered" : {
                        "filter" : {
                            "terms" : { 
                                "price" : [20, 30]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I tried this:

```
    val res =  ESclient.execute {
        search in "index" query {
          filteredQuery query {
            matchall
          } filter {
                   termsFilter("category", Array(1,2))
          }
        }
```

But got an error from ES.

How can I do that?

Comment: Grr. "But got an error from ES." What error? Please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Paul not a meaningful error: `(internal:    ,{"error":"[elastic1][inet[/xxx.xx.xx.xx:9300]][search]"})`

Comment: There was no stack trace with it ?. Can you try termsFilter("category", Array(1,2) : _* ) until I can get time to test it properly

Comment: @monkjack yes works. why is that?

Comment: I will write a full reply to explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling termsFilter, the method is expecting a var args invocation of `Any*`, so `termsFilter("category", 1, 2)` would work. But `termsFilter("category", Array(1,2))` is treated as a single argument, since Array is a subclass of Any of course. By adding `: _ *` we force scala to see it as a vars arg invocation.

So this will work:

```
val res =  ESclient.execute {
  search in "index" query {
    filteredQuery query {
      matchall
   } filter {
        termsFilter("category", Array(1,2) : _ *)
   }
}
```

Maybe the best solution of all is to update the client to be overloaded on Iterables.